# The Mix manifest does not exist. (View: /media/Disk2/project1/resources/views/projects/assets.blade.php)

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-mix

The manifest-json file exist in /public/manifest-json.js, but application shows the error like

> The Mix manifest does not exist. (View: >/media/Disk2/project1/resources/views/projects/assets.blade.php)

In my resources/views/projects/assets.blade.php file,

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('styles/style.scss', 'pc') }}" media="screen,print">
```

The style.scss file located in resources/assets/pc/styles/ folder
And in the webpack.mix.pc.js

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');


mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve('./resources/assets'),
            path.resolve('./node_modules')
        ]
    }
})

mix.setPublicPath('public/pc');

mix.js('resources/assets/pc/scripts/orgs.js', 'scripts')
    .
    .
    .
    .extract([
        'babel-polyfill',
        'vue',
        'axios',
        'vue-router',
        'qs',
        'intersection-observer',
        'element-ui',
        'twemoji'
    ])
    .sass('resources/assets/pc/styles/style.scss', 'styles');
```

**Laravel Framework  version : 5.6.40
AND the same project worked on windows machine,only Linux machine has the error**

I tried the following methods but none of them worked to me.

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest --save-dev
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=telescope-assets --force
npm install & npm run dev
```

**mix-manifest.json**

```
{
    "/scripts/vendor.js": "/scripts/vendor.js?id=7af01ba1fe4d1a02c057",
    "/scripts/projects.js": "/scripts/projects.js?id=9085908d36da948da0d2",
    "/scripts/projects.create.js": "/scripts/projects.create.js?id=0e2c9cf0b1d557b9ebea",
    "/scripts/alignment.js": "/scripts/alignment.js?id=81a2c8dc009675ca6a63",
    "/scripts/library.js": "/scripts/library.js?id=fe12cfe65102df09f157",
    "/scripts/schedules.js": "/scripts/schedules.js?id=bee62dde22aa6a6edf7b",
    "/scripts/reports.js": "/scripts/reports.js?id=0fbdc5feead9ce05d3d3",
    "/scripts/projects.html-preview.js": "/scripts/projects.html-preview.js?id=8c45d7c373adb9b640ab",
    "/scripts/projects.html-diff.js": "/scripts/projects.html-diff.js?id=0131a949331213bee864",
    "/scripts/projects.info.js": "/scripts/projects.info.js?id=06b24a4333942e24559f",
    "/scripts/progress.js": "/scripts/progress.js?id=ff1d09b1bb27c4737a69",
    "/scripts/messages.js": "/scripts/messages.js?id=67f9fff3baca80d30bf4",
    "/scripts/orgs.js": "/scripts/orgs.js?id=8861ff1e75be6dd6acc4",
    "/styles/projects.css": "/styles/projects.css?id=ee9a376c8e544ac96d21",
    "/styles/projects.info.css": "/styles/projects.info.css?id=da6462e737e5f9d7fc7b",
    "/styles/projects.create.css": "/styles/projects.create.css?id=54e923d8c1775ec1f35d",
    "/styles/messages.css": "/styles/messages.css?id=a8d7cfd25c41e0346d1a",
    "/styles/library.css": "/styles/library.css?id=313ecb61c93dca3d045b",
    "/styles/schedules.css": "/styles/schedules.css?id=17cc37c59d984730524f",
    "/styles/progress.css": "/styles/progress.css?id=48436f44b7c757bb0e56",
    "/styles/menus.css": "/styles/menus.css?id=a875f862cdd16610480b",
    "/styles/projects.html-preview.css": "/styles/projects.html-preview.css?id=4288943cf81e98c4a7af",
    "/styles/projects.html-diff.css": "/styles/projects.html-diff.css?id=026d0f65e0145d01fbf5",
    "/styles/style.css": "/styles/style.css?id=a5666d65010fadb247bb",
    "/styles/report.css": "/styles/report.css?id=bc99951d98b0476eef17",
    "/styles/alignment.css": "/styles/alignment.css?id=f23a2d8a3e0a89b22c47",
    "/scripts/release-info.js": "/scripts/release-info.js?id=8713d126e68638f15cf7",
    "/scripts/manifest.js": "/scripts/manifest.js?id=40a46559aecf12a64c83"
}
```

Comment: Comment out the line `mix.setPublicPath('public/pc');` and retry.

Comment: @Donkarnash I tried but still same error is displaying

Comment: Sorry missed **pc** in `mix('styles/style.scss', 'pc')`, uncomment the line `mix.setPublicPath('public/pc');` and check if `mix-manifest.json` file exists in `public/pc`. If it doesn't exist, run `npm run dev` again and check if `public/pc/mix-manifest.json` exists. Also include markup for `<script>` tags

Comment: And it should be `mix('styles/style.css', 'pc')` **css** not **scss** in the `mix()` call

Comment: mix-manifest.json file exist in /public folder. And there is no /public/pc/ folder. 
 resources/assets/pc folder is there. 
This was an old project done by someone else so i don't know why they set  public/pc as publicPath.

Comment: So if you remove the line `mix.setPublicPath('public/pc')` and run `npm dev` are compiled files created in the `public/styles` and `public/scripts` folders.? If yes then change the mix calls to `mix('styles/style.css')` removing `, 'pc'`. The path `styles/style.css` passed to the `mix` call should be relative to `mix-manifest.json` file if it is in `public` folder then `styles/style.css` should be at `public/styles/style.css` and similarly js files should be within `'public/scripts`

Comment: Removed the `mix.setPublicPath('public/pc')` line and executed  the `npm run dev` , the files are created as mentioned above, and removed **pc** also in the path but error is still there

Comment: Try `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan clear-compiled` then retry and check if that works. If it doesn't paste the markup for `<script>` tags as well as content of `min-manifest.json`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245337/discussion-between-jyothis-and-donkarnash).